# compare char with int in loop

Tags: c, loops

my program is taking an argument which says how many prints that should be used.
example of arguments: prints 2.
I then want to loop through the value after prints, the number 2. and then print that many times. I tried like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < argv[2]; i++)
{
     ....
```

The problem is that argv is a char and i is an int. So when I run this loop, argv[2] aquire the value: 123123123 or something, instead of just 2. Is there any way around this or to compare the value in a char with an int. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

argv[2] is a `char*` not a `char`. argv[2] points to a string( array of null terminated characters ). When you pass an arguments to you program, the argument is in that form.

You will have to convert it, you can use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) ;

Answer (score 0):

`argv[2]` is `char*`, is string in C language, if you want to change it to int, you must
convert it. Convert String to int.
Here is an example:

```
int atoi(char *str){//Just suit for int
    int ans = 0,i=0;
    while(str[i]){
        ans = ans*10 + (str[i]-'0');
        i++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

You can call it like this `atoi(argv[2]);`